# PHP written alternative to OpenGrok

Tags: php, svn, indexing, cross-reference, opengrok

Is there an equivalent of opengrok or any code indexer tool with a php frontend ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a source code cross-referencer, you may have a look at [PHPXref](http://phpxref.sourceforge.net/).

If you want to browse SCM history, then you can turn to [WebSVN](http://websvn.tigris.org/) or  [GitPHP](http://www.gitphp.org/projects/gitphp/wiki).

Otherwise, you will have to look at PERL alternatives like [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) or [LXR](http://lxr.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: All LXR links have changed from -.shtml to -.php. Link above is now http://lxr.sourceforge.net/en/index.php or, shorter with content negociation, http://lxr.sourceforge.net

Comment: Thanks @ajlittoz, link fixed!